# Ternary Relationship - Is This Sentence One?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, ternary

I am trying to determine whether or not a relationship is ternary via a sentence. So the following relationship is:

Every patient has had at least one procedure but not every surgeon has carried out a procedure.

I want to say that this is not ternary due to the fact that there isnt necessarily a link between surgeon and patient that is explicitly stated but I'm not entirely sure if that is correct.

Comment: If all procedures are performed by surgeons then there will always be a link between a patient/surgeon and surgeon/patient. (And there may be a relationship between a patient and two surgeons, but that's a separate conversation.) For any *given* patient/surgeon there may or may not be a relationship.

Comment: So could I imply that it is a ternary relationship being that there should always be a link between a surgeon and a patient, even if it isnt explicitly stated?